# Drag and drop Javascript in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari

I need to develop drag and drop functionality in iPad. As I am new to Javascript, I tried to get some solution to get this thing done. I could find the way to move the element on the screen.

Here the the url
http://popdevelop.com/2010/08/touching-the-web/

Now what I want to know is, when I drag any element, I need to put it in a predefined area, like drag from x container and putting into y container.

I need help to create drop-able container, so that I could drag and drop into the container.

Some thing similar to the below functionality I need to create in iPad.

http://html5demos.com/drag

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/ for drag and drop functionality and then add this script https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch for playing it in Ipad or Iphone.

OR

Try this :
jquery.event.drag - v 2.2
Three Dub Media - http://threedubmedia.com

Hope it helps.